# Trouble with fourth type of irreducible character of GL2(F) Serge Lang algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

so it's been 1 month since I started reading Serge Lang Algebra, I'm now pretty advanced in my reading of the book but I am stuck at p 721, here it is :

[image]

So here Lang is computing and classifying all the irreducible complex characters of the general linear group of dimension 2 over a finite field.

The part I'm having trouble with is when he constructs the fourth type of irreducible character, specifically the claim :

"Note that a direct computation using Frobenius reciprocity shows that θᴳ occurs in the character (res θ , λ)ᴳ."

If you want to see how he defines the two characters, here it is :

[image]

So I've tried to show that θᴳ occurs in the decomposition of (res θ , λ)ᴳ into a linear combination of irreducible characters, but to me it's not at all clear how to do it because we're dealing with reducible characters.

I've been able to show that θ occurs in the linear decomposition of the restriction of (res θ , λ)ᴳ to the group associated to the character θ. I simply used the inner product (or bilinear form if you want) of the characters and the orthogonality relations of irreducible characters.

But I cannot extend my methods to prove that θᴳ is contained in (res θ , λ)ᴳ because those characters are reducible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot comment for I don't have a copy of Lang. Have you looked at other sources? I once ran a study group working on Kowalski's lecture notes on representation theory. I found the way he constructed the irreducible reps of $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$ quite accessible. It should be possible to port that here (assuming this class matches with the one Kowalski calls *cuspidal*). Kowalski's notes were at least downloadable from ETH webpage. His book has been printed since the time I did that, so that may have changed...

Comment: Kowalski's doesn't construct the fourth type of irreducible character the same way as Serge Lang does, so sadly it doesn't help us to understand Lang's claim. Also, Serge Lang's book "Algebra" is freely downloadable in pdf on the internet.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm on vacation, so somewhat stuck with the books I have at home (and many of those only due to the impact COVID had on my work habits). I suspect somebody here has a copy of Lang at home, and can take a closer look. There are plenty of people here better versed in rep theory than I ever was.